# How to show native iOS views in a Flutter application?

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am currently working on a project in which I need to implement a graphical framework that has been written for Android and iOS; however, I am writing the application using Flutter/Dart, and so far I can not find any way for showing native iOS views in a Flutter application. I have found a module written for android that claims to do this ([blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/communication-between-flutter-and-native-modules-9b52c6a72dd2)), and I am curious if anyone knows of any modules or techniques that can achieve this for iOS.

I know that Flutter has the ChannelMethod feature, but that is not a solution-at least from my understanding, ChannelMethods can pass platform-specific messages, but this does not help me show a platform-specific plugin in a Flutter application.

It has also occurred to me to hard code an equivalent graphic interface in Flutter and then use ChannelMethods to pass the needed data, but this is not ideal because it appears that not all data I would need from the plugin is easily available. I'm really looking for a way to show the UIView in Flutter somehow.

Is there any way to show a native iOS view in a Flutter application? 
Alternatively, is there any way to segue to a iOS viewController from a Flutter application?

Comment: Did you see? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19030#issuecomment-437534853

Comment: You can do it through flutter channels

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flutter Platform Views](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views?tab=ios-platform-views-swift-tab#ios) to display platform native widgets in the Flutter app.

In the sample given in the docs, `FLNativeViewFactory` creates the platform view, and it provides a reference to the `UIView`. The iOS Views can be added using the provided `UIView` reference.

Using Swift

```swift
class FLNativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
  init(
    frame: CGRect,
    viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
    arguments args: Any?,
    binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
  ){
    _view = UIView()
    super.init()
    // iOS views can be added here
  }
}
```

Using Objective-C

```objectivec
@implementation FLNativeView {
   UIView *_view;
}
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
               viewIdentifier:(int64_t)viewId
                    arguments:(id _Nullable)args
              binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _view = [[UIView alloc] init];
  }
  // iOS views can be added here
  return self;
}

@end
```